# How to specify used Library dependency in Robot Framework like maven-pom in java?

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

Im new to Robotframework coming from java-selenium background. I have created tested cases using libraries robotframework-requestlibrary, seleniumlibrary. I installed these using pip install, but now if I want to pass on my test-scripts, others will not be able to run as they also need to install these libraries.

How we specify libraries used in Robot Framework like we have pom.xml in Java and `mvn clean install` will get it setup for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:** Use freeze cmd in your machine in command line to get the libraries installed with version no.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

**Step 2:** Include this requirements.txt file while giving your test scripts to others and ask them to run the below command in command line before they run the robot scripts

**Note:** open command line in the requirements.txt file path

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

That's it!